# Maya Python modules complete documentation?

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I've started using Python to script Maya for a school projet but i'm facing a problem with the documentation : I can't find anywhere a complete documentation of all the modules classes and function of the Maya API.

I've already foun the Python-style documentation for [PyMEL module](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/JPN/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/index.html), but where is the reste of it ? E.g, the `maya.cmds` module ?

Thanks.

Comment: For the record, anything I've ever used from `maya.cmds` also worked with `pymel.core`. Maybe some advanced functions that are rarely used may not be compatible between the two, but if you're just doing general stuff, pymel should be fine. `maya.OpenMaya` is the API - http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/group___open_maya.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the maya help inside of Maya (the `F1` key in windows) or go to [the online documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2015/ENU/) (that link goes to the maya 2015 docs, your copy of Maya should have the right URL for your version).  The commands are documented under **Python Commands** in the **Technical Documentation** chapter; the python API is documented in **Maya Developer Help** under **Maya Python API**.

Comment: Thank you. I admit I didn't even looked  at that Technical documentation section. One more question : what is the difference between the Python commands and the Maya API ? Do they provide the same functions or are they complementary ?

Comment: cmds is the automation interface -it's basically a wrapper around MEL, for scripting a series of operations using the ordinary maya tools.  The API lets you get at the C++ internals.  In general, stick with cmds unless you have a compelling need : the API , like C++, can crash your maya where the worst you can do with cmds is to generate an error message