# Python With Maya Selecting Object and Rotating It

Tags: python, python-3.x, maya

So I am working on a very small project, and I need to have an object rotated one or two times per minute, and I need to do it using Python.  Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks so much.

Comment: you can use expressions or change the rotation with cmds.rotate, cmds.xform, cmds.setAttr in combinaison of simple math and maybe keyframing : cmds.setKeyframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `rotate` function?...

```
from maya import cmds   
cmds.select(object1)
cmds.rotate(0, 0, 10, relative=True, componentSpace=True)
```

[Maya 2018, python, move and rotate extracted face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268390/maya-2018-python-move-and-rotate-extracted-face)

[Maya Python modules complete documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446321/maya-python-modules-complete-documentation)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much.  I'm just starting on Maya, so this really helps.

Comment: This is the right way to do it in a tool , ie, if you want to do this using a button or a menu item or a small script.  You don't want to do this 'live' during an animation.